# How can I autoload a custom class in Laravel 5.1?

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, autoload

I've created a `library` folder within the `app` folder to add my own classes.

[image]

This is the content of the file `app/library/helper.php`:

```
<?php

namespace Library;

class MyHelper
{
    public function v($arr)
    {
        var_dump($arr);
    }
}
```

I added the namespace to `composer.json`:

[image]

and then I ran

```
$ composer dump-autoload
```

but it does not seem to have any effects.

The files

- `vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php`
- `vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php`

did not change.

If I try to create an instance of `MyHelper`, Laravel reports the following error:

[image]

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 12):

Your autoloading configuration is almost good, but you have

- got the namespaces wrong
- got the paths wrong

To fix the problem, adjust your autoloading configuration:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    }
}
```

Then rename the directory `/library` to `/Library` (note the case).

Then rename the file `/app/Library/helper.php` to `/app/Library/MyHelper.php` (note how class name should match the file name).

Then adjust the namespace of the class provided by `/app/Library/MyHelper` to match the PSR-4 prefix (and thus the structure of your project), as well as usages of the class:

```
namespace App\Library;

class MyHelper 
{
    public function v($arr)
    {
        var_dump($arr);
    }
}
```

For reference, see:

- http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/

Answer (score 10):

Use `files` directive in `composer.json`: https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#files

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "files": ["app/library/helper.php"]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use composer.json :

```
   "autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database",
        "app/Transformers"
    ]
 },
```

Add your auto load directories like I added app/Transformers.

Don't Forget to add run `composer dump-autoload`.

The only problem with this method is you need to run `composer dump-autoload` whenever you add new class do that directory.

Or You can use "Files" in composer.json.

```
"autoload": {
    "files": ["src/MyLibrary/functions.php"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question was answered a while ago, but the reason it isn't working is that you need to give the namespace that corresponds with the file structure. Therefore, since the Library class is inside the App folder you need:

```
namespace App\Library;

class MyHelper{
    public function v($arr){
        var_dump($arr);
    }
}
```

Additionally, if you are going to call the class `MyHelper`, you need to call the file MyHelper.php

Comment: No, it says `App\Library`.

Comment: Oh I didn't realize you used lower case. In Laravel it will recognize both upper case and lower case for the file structure. I have had a folder called `library` and namespace `Library` and it worked