# Laravel 5.4 Auto Include of Yajra Datatables

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

Is there any way to auto include Yajra in Controller ? cause everytime I make a controller php artisan make:controller
I always copy paste this Provider,

```
use Yajra\Datatables\Facades\Datatables;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the best design pattern, You should load that class on all your controllers. Why not adding alias for that class instead so you don't need to copy the whole namespace,

On your `app/config.php` find `aliases`

```
'aliases' => [
    .......
    .......
    'Datatables' => Yajra\Datatables\Facades\Datatables::class,
]
```

then on your controller just use is like this

```
Use Datatables;
```

But if you insist to autoload that class try to find the file's directory and try this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31917950/how-to-autoload-my-class-in-laravel5-1).

Goodluck!

Comment: Thanks for this ill settle for aliases

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do this with the help of your IDE not the framework itself.

For example you can use Phpstorm's [Live templates](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/live-templates.html)